# How to run VS 2015 tests using VS2017 Vstest.console.exe

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have tests built in vs2015. I installed vstest.console from https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/contribute.md#building-with-visual-studio following the steps. 
Now when I try to run tests using `“c:\VSTest\vstest\src\vstest.console\bin\Debug\net451\win7-x64\vstest.console.exe” “c:\mydll.dll’` 
It gives me following error:

> No suitable test runtime provider found for this run.

What should I do. I’m a novice and need help. Please let me know what should I do to run my tests.
Note: Using MsTest it runs just fine
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should install Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition is free), and then from the Start menu open "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" and run `vstest.console.exe` from there.